# Mapbox JS, GeoJSON featureCollection object from URL only adds one marker

Tags: javascript, mapbox

This map, http://lastablaslift.es/explorador/, is loading a local CSV file through the csv2geojson plugin, to add some markers with popups to it.

We are trying to put together a URL endpoint to get geoJSON from a mysql DB instead of a CSV.

This map, http://lastablaslift.es/explorador/map_test.php, is the same but uses geoJSON from our URL.

It seems like we have got the URL returning correctly formatted GeoJSON, but as you can see, only the first object in the "features" array is being rendered on map_test.php

I am logging both geoJSON objects to the console, and when I compare them, they look the same to me. No pertinent errors are being reported either, so what is wrong with the geoJSON from our URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dehjrr8m/)  example.I think there will be problem related to `function change() {}`, that you placed in $.getJSON success function. Try to put it outside.
Your **map_jsonurl.js** sholud look like this,

```
(function() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        if (image.width > 0) {
            document.documentElement.className += (document.documentElement.className != '') ? ' images-on' : 'images-on';
        }
    };
    image.src = '/img/px.png';
}());

//toggle the filter menu
/*$("#f_tog").on("click", function(){
    $("#filters").slideToggle();
    $("#f_tog span").toggle();
});*/

// load the map data
$.getJSON("//civicliftmapeurope.azurewebsites.net/api/Listing", function(data) {

    //initialize the map
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'ptw111.lgof8gop')
        .setView([40.5023056, -3.6704803], 14);

    //center marker on click
    map.markerLayer.on('click', function(e) {
        map.panTo(e.layer.getLatLng());
    });

    // Add custom popups to each using our custom feature properties
    map.featureLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
        var marker = e.layer,
            feature = marker.feature;

        //string functions, cleaning up geoJSON for display.

        //clean up address
        var addr;
        var zip = feature.properties.zip;

        if (feature.properties.addr) {
            addr = feature.properties.addr + ', ' + zip + '<br>' + feature.properties.city + ', Espa&ntilde;a';
        }

        //check for description
        var desc;

        if (feature.properties.description) {
            desc = feature.properties.description;
        } else {
            desc = '';
        }

        //check for phone numbers
        var phone;

        if (feature.properties.phone) {
            phone = '<strong>' + feature.properties.phone + '</strong>';
        } else {
            phone = '';
        }

        // create custom popup content
        var popupContent = '<div class="tooltip"><h2>' + feature.properties.name + '</h2>' +
            phone +
            '<div class="addr"><p>' +
            addr +
            '</p></div><span>' +
            desc +
            '</span></div>';

        // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup
        marker.bindPopup(popupContent, {
            closeButton: false,
            minWidth: 150,
        });
    });

    // Add features to the map
    map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(data);

    //filter locations by color/type
    var filters = document.getElementById('filters');
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('filter');

    // When the form is touched, re-filter markers
       filters.onchange = change;
    // Initially filter the markers
       change();

});

function change() {
    // Find all checkboxes that are checked and build a list of their values
    var on = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) on.push(checkboxes[i].value);
    }
    // The filter function takes a GeoJSON feature object
    // and returns true to show it or false to hide it.
    map.markerLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
        // check each marker's color to see if its value is in the list
        // of colors that should be on, stored in the 'on' array
        return on.indexOf(f.properties['marker-color']) !== -1;
    });
    return false;
}
```